# LAMP stack mail keeps going to spam

Tags: ubuntu, smtp, digital-ocean

We recently migrated to a new server. On the old one we could send emails out from both the command line and our web app without an issue. On the new server running Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache and PHP7 I set up postfix as a send-only smtp server by following [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-16-04).

The emails that were sent both from the command line and the web app could send, but they went to spam. After installing and configuring OpenDKIM, and setting up the zone file, I still can't get an email to get to an inbox. They keep going to spam.

If it makes a difference, our server hosts two websites. Our front facing website is example.com, but the websites on our server are app.example.com and example.bz. Example.com is hosted somewhere else. I want to send mail from noreply@app.example.com.

What do I need to do to get my emails to not go to spam?

Comment: where is your domain hosted? is it on gmail? or do you have your own mail server?

Comment: So example.com runs our work emails, but app.example.com is hosted on Digital Ocean.

Comment: please go to https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/ and write your domain there, and check what are the issues concerning mails that are related to your domain. fix the serious and moderate issues and your emails should be sent to inbox by then